# How to format cells based on their values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this logic to give cell colors for selected cell range with values.

```
If value > 75
  cell color = BLUE
Else if value > 50
  cell color = RED
Else
  cell color = BLACK
```

how can I use this logic in excel to color cells based on their values?

Comment: There is an option called conditional format. It is on menu, where depends on the program you are using

Answer (score 2):

### Macro

Write this in the appropriated Sheet's module (<kbd>+Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>)

**Updated**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value > 75 Then
        Target.Interior.Color = 12611584
    ElseIf Target.Value > 50 Then
        Target.Interior.Color = 255
    Else
        Target.Interior.Color = 0
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

### Conditional formating

1. Step1
   [image: Step1]
2. Step2
   [image: Step2]

### Explain

**For Blue**

- Range: Desired. For example using entire Sheet's range in Excel 2007 is `=$1:$1048576`
- Formula: Use the first cell of the range. (For above example that is `A1`): `=A1>75`

**For Red**

- Range: Desired. For example using entire Sheet's range in Excel 2007 is `=$1:$1048576`
- Formula: Use the first cell of the range. (For above example that is `A1`):`=A1>50`

**For Black**

- Range: Desired. For example using entire Sheet's range in Excel 2007 is `=$1:$1048576`
- Formula: Use the first cell of the range. (For above example that is `A1`):`=AND(NOT(A1>50),ISNUMBER(A1))`

Comment: @Pnuts, The question is about Cell's color. Not about the numbers format.